# Tracking screen views in Flutter with Firebase Analytics

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

What is the best location for manually logging a screen view in Flutter with an analytics package (in my case I am using Firebase Analytics, eg. [track screens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews))?

Looking at the Flutter lifecycle, it's not clear where it makes sense to track a screen view.

For a `StatelessWidget`, I think `build()` might make sense as I guess it's only called one time per screen view.

What about for a `StatefulWidget` though? In this case `build()` would not be useful as it could be called many times. Other candidates are `initState()`, `createState()` or the constructor which all appear to only be called once although I'm guessing they may all be called more than once per screen view as widgets up the hierarchy are re-built.

Comment: You are right, for `StatelessWidget` it should be the `build()` method and for `StatefulWidget` you can use `initState()` however in both the cases data can be changed from outside and passed to them so this is not 100% accurate depending how you are implementing it.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad thanks, thats kind of what I figured, so it sounds like there isn't really a fantastic solution here :(

Comment: Sir, you are a Googler, you have direct access to the Flutter team, you should be a message away to get this answered for you and ourselves. Thanks you gentleman :)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Hah, I don't work on the Flutter team but I can ask them. I prefer to ask and answer on SO though so others can see the answers :) That said, I will see if I can get one of the team to chime in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is: it depends. For a `StatelessWidget`, it might be suitable to have an Analytics event in `build()`, but only if the parent widgets are not re-built frequently. For a `StatefulWidget` the same applies but you also have to factor in re-builds due to state change (which are, more than likely often).

Really, the safest path is not to call Analytics events in any parts of the widget lifecycle, but instead on the UI event that might trigger a screen, for example, an edit button that opens up an edit screen. However, the problem with that approach is that the screen might be opened from a variety of locations within the app (meaning you have to duplicate Analytics calls across all those locations).

This means the best option is probably to tie Analytics to `PageRoute` transitions so that it is called consistently whenever a page route is executed. This is demonstrated in the [docs](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_analytics). This will miss tracking screens within a tab bar and other types of UI navigation but as the docs also say, one way to handle this is to implement `RouteAware` and subscribing it to `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` ([example tabs implementation](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/example/lib/tabs_page.dart)).